# add event to summernote when code view activated

Tags: jquery, summernote

How to add event to summernote when code view activated?

I want to trigger keyup action when typing code. I'm trying with this but it does not work well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#summernote').on('summernote.init', function () {
        $('#summernote').summernote('codeview.activate');
    }).summernote({
        height: 300,
        toolbar: [],
        codemirror: {
            theme: 'monokai'
        }
    });

    $('#summernote').on('summernote.keyup', function(we, e) {
        console.log('Key is released:', e.keyCode);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution as noted on Summernote's website:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onKeyup: function(e) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Key is released:', e.keyCode);
      },200);
    }
 }
});
```

There are also a ton of other callback events that can be found here including the init event: https://summernote.org/deep-dive/

```
//You need to call summernote and add the callback then add your summernote.init event

$('#summernote').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onInit: function() {
   console.log('Summernote is launched');
}
}
});
```

Comment: this is correct but it doesn't work when i add onInit to initialize  summernote

Comment: @carrow my answer was revised.  Do you see any errors in console regarding your init event?

Comment: What version of summernote and jquery are you using?